# Is bool check faster than null check?

Tags: c#, performance

E.g. do I need to extract

```
bool xIsNull = x == null
```

from the loop where I check `x == null`?

As I know `if (a == true)` and `if (x == null)` both use the same IL instruction. But pointers consist of 32 or 64 bits. Does CLR should check every bit to compare with null?

**UPDATE**
Quick test shows that there is no difference but I still would like somebody to explain this.

**UPDATE2**
I use IL emitting so I can't expect compiler to optimize my code. Only by JIT.

Comment: Would some nanoseconds make that big difference?

Comment: Give question a chance

Comment: If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster [then race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: This question suggests you know very little about hardware and compilation. That's fine, you don't *need* to know any of that to be a software developer. But you should know your limits: If you want to reason about performance at this level, you *must* know this stuff. Reasoning about performance without such knowledge is as futile as predicting the flight of a Space Shuttle without physics knowledge.

Comment: For something so simple, just trust the JITter and move on to something that's actually important.

Comment: @spender (Accurately) judging when something can be left to the JIT compiler, or is otherwise irrelevant, already requires a degree of knowledge which OP apparently does not possess.

Comment: If you need `ns`, then C# is a wrong language. Otherwise *optimized loop* gain is not that big. There are countless scenarios where you *let* something to stay inside the loop (to example, adding constant to a value), because you loose only 1 CPU operation for that, which is in most scenarios unimportant. But *if you care*, then you need to dig much deeper, because you can not trust compiler (which may or may not optimize things for you) than and have to produce IL yourself probably.

Comment: Yes, I produce IL myself. That's why I am asking. See question update.

Comment: The reason why there no difference, is probably because both are compiled to something what take same time => no gain. Question like this is too much pedantic. Yes, everybody knows what you should put *obviously* slowing things out of the loop. But up to which extent? Fastest algorithm are written in the specific CPU commands. But rarely peoples program on this level (I am programming micro-controllers myself). It is much more comfortable to use at least C for that. Unless I need every bit, then I switch to asm.

Comment: @BoltClock I just like to understand how things work)

Comment: I came here to check for exactly what Vlad asked, because I am adding a new feature to a method that processes high loads of data. Because of this, I want to be able to turn off the new feature, if it proves of being too expensive ... now I know from BlackBears answer that the most cost effective way to turn it off, is setting the target variable to null and use a null check. There _always_ is a use case!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remembering that "Premature Optimization is the Root of all Evil" and that the first rule of optimization is "Don't" (the second, only for pros, is "Don't Do it Yet"), here's what happens.

**TL;DR**
If you don't feel like diving into some assembly code I won't blame you ;) Results show that using a temporary variable does not get optimized out and generates a couple more instructions. Summing it up, though, it's not going to make any difference unless you are coding *very* time critical tasks.

---

Consider this code:

```
string x = null;
bool a = x == null;

if ( a == true ) { Console.WriteLine( ); }
if ( x == null ) { Console.WriteLine( ); }
```

This is the generated IL in *Debug* mode (I added some comments):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       46 (0x2e)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string x,
           [1] bool a,
           [2] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  stloc.0    // string x = null
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldnull
  IL_0005:  ceq        // compare x and null
  IL_0007:  stloc.1    // and store the result in a
  IL_0008:  ldloc.1
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0 
  IL_000a:  ceq
  IL_000c:  stloc.2    // compare a and false
  IL_000d:  ldloc.2
  IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0018   // if true (that is, a is false), skip
  IL_0010:  nop
  IL_0011:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  nop
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  ldnull  
  IL_001a:  ceq        // compare x and null
  IL_001c:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001d:  ceq        // and compare with false
  IL_001f:  stloc.2
  IL_0020:  ldloc.2
  IL_0021:  brtrue.s   IL_002b  // if true (that is, x == null), skip
  IL_0023:  nop
  IL_0024:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
  IL_0029:  nop
  IL_002a:  nop
  IL_002b:  br.s       IL_002d
  IL_002d:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Overall, there are a lot of ldloc and stloc which read and write data to memory; they are highly reduntant to help the debugger. But you can see that there is an hidden local variable which has the exact same function as a: so if you don't use a temporary variable the compiler is going to use it for you. Also note the use of a generic `null`.

Now here's the *Release* IL with optimizations enabled:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       24 (0x18)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string x,
           [1] bool a)
  IL_0000:  ldnull
  IL_0001:  stloc.0     // set x to null
  IL_0002:  ldloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldnull
  IL_0004:  ceq
  IL_0006:  stloc.1     // bool a = x == null
  IL_0007:  ldloc.1
  IL_0008:  brfalse.s  IL_000f  // if false skip
  IL_000a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
  IL_000f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0010:  brtrue.s   IL_0017  // if true (so x != null) skip
  IL_0012:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
  IL_0017:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

In the optimized version the compiler does not perform explicit comparisons and does not use a temp variable. Still, like in the unoptimized version, it stores a and loads it right after that to check for the condition; this is because `stloc` pops a out of the stack so it has to push it again.

Now, let's compare the code generated by the JITter (I set x = Console.Readline() to prevent the whole code being optimized out). This is for the debug configuration (as seen in Visual Studio):

```
            string x = null;
00000043  xor         edx,edx 
00000045  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx 
            bool a = x == null;
00000048  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-40h],0 
0000004c  sete        al 
0000004f  movzx       eax,al 
00000052  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax 

            if ( a == true ) { Console.WriteLine( ); }
00000055  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-44h],0 
00000059  sete        al 
0000005c  movzx       eax,al 
0000005f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax 
00000062  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-48h],0 
00000066  jne         00000070 
00000068  nop 
00000069  call        6027B57C 
0000006e  nop 
0000006f  nop 
            if ( x == null ) { Console.WriteLine( ); }
00000054  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],0 
00000058  jne         00000065 
0000005a  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0350208Ch] 
00000060  call        602DD5E0 
            return;
00000065  nop 
00000066  mov         esp,ebp 
00000068  pop         ebp 
00000069  ret
```

As you can see, this code follows closely the corresponding unoptimized IL and uses a temporary variable when checking the condition for a. On the other hand, since null is implemented as 0 on my machine, comparing `x` and `null` is way quicker.

And here's the code for the release as seen through OllyDbg:

```
                string x = Console.ReadLine( );
002F0075    E8 EA808A60     CALL mscorlib_ni.60B98164
002F007A    8BC8            MOV ECX, EAX
002F007C    8B01            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
002F007E    8B40 2C         MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+2C]
002F0081    FF50 1C         CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+1C]

                bool a = x == null;
002F0084    8BF0            MOV ESI, EAX
002F0086    85F6            TEST ESI, ESI
002F0088    0F94C0          SETE AL
002F008B    0FB6C0          MOVZX EAX, AL
002F008E    8BF8            MOV EDI, EAX

                Systed.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break( );
002F0090    E8 E37C8E60     CALL mscorlib_ni.60BD7D78

                if ( a == true ) { Console.ReadLine( ); }
002F0095    85FF            TEST EDI, EDI
002F0097    74 0E           JE SHORT 002F00A7
002F0099    E8 A6F92D60     CALL mscorlib_ni.605CFA44
002F009E    8BC8            MOV ECX, EAX
002F00A0    8B01            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
002F00A2    8B40 38         MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+38]
002F00A5    FF10            CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]

                if ( x == null ) { Console.ReadLine( ); }
002F00A7    85F6            TEST ESI, ESI
002F00A9    75 0E           JNE SHORT 002F00B9
002F00AB    E8 94F92D60     CALL mscorlib_ni.605CFA44
002F00B0    8BC8            MOV ECX, EAX
002F00B2    8B01            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
002F00B4    8B40 38         MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+38]
002F00B7    FF10            CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]

                return;
002F00B9    5E              POP ESI
002F00BA    5F              POP EDI
002F00BB    5D              POP EBP
002F00BC    C3              RETN
```

In this code, `a` is held in `edi` and `x` is held in `esi` and there are some calls to mscorlib to retrieve the pointers to ReadLine and WriteLine. That being said, there actually is a difference between the two approaches; after comparing `x` with `null` (`test esi, esi`) the result is moved from the zero flag to al (`sete al`), then extended to the whole `eax` (`movzx eax, al`).

So, even in such a simple case, the JITter isn't doing a good work; therefore, you can expect a *minor* performance gain without the temporary variable.

Comment: So I should not use bool variable for null checking. Thank you for summing up

Answer (score 2):

So with modern compilation and hardware optimizations I doubt there would be enough performance difference to make enough difference to worry about (if any).

Part of the point higher level languages like C# is to take these insignificant optimization details out of the hands of app devs and leave them to compiler devs who will do it much better and free up app devs to make their decisions off of readability/maintainablity and spend more time on high level algorithmic efficiency rather than the low level stuff. If you are having performance issues this is probably the least of your worries.

Bottom line I would recommend using whatever you feels makes your code most readable.

Comment: Such optimizations are not insignificant when *compared* with other also very fast things.

Comment: I didn't see your later update about IL emit but it is important for this answer to be here for other people who find this question later who are not optimizing at that level.

Answer (score -1):

Do not concern yourself with microoptimizations. Whichever one is "fastest" will undoubtedly have zero effect on your web app. Use whichever is clearest for you and other programmers to read.

Unless you have measured and found that there is a problem with your code, and you know exactly where in the code is being slow, you are wasting your time.

Programmer time is many orders of magnitude more expensive than computer time.